# Qual nome se dá ao único que vota de forma contrária a todos os outros?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia

Uma conhecida expressão é [voto de Minerva](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voto_de_Minerva), que designa um voto final de desempate. Por exemplo, dentre 13 pessoas, se 6 votam X e 6 votam Y, cabe ao último o desempate, o voto de Minerva.

Há uma expressão análoga para o único que vota de forma contrária a todos os outros? Por exemplo, uma votação é encerrada com 12 pessoas tendo votado X e apenas uma tendo votado Y.

Answer (score 2):

pode ser chamado de “o do contra”.

Answer (score 2):

Pode também chamá-lo de "voto vencido por unanimidade".

Ele nem devia ter levado o caso a votação. Tinhamos a certeza de que ele seria "voto vencido".

Comment: Centaurus, não é "por unanimidade" quando todos votaram a favor? Pergunto, pois, Loremlpsum está perguntando quando todos menos um votaram a favor

Comment: Eu entendo que o voto foi vencido por unanimidade, porque ele não foi vencido por mais da metade dos votantes, mas sim por 100% daqueles que votaram (excluindo o que foi voto vencido, é claro) . Houve unanimidade em não aceitar o voto contrário.  Não sei se ficou claro o meu ponto de vista.

Comment: @Schilive  Foi um voto vencido por **todos** os outros votantes.  Não estou a falar de unanimidade a favor ou contra o que estava sendo votado, mas unanimidade em fazer do voto contrário, um voto vencido.

Comment: Concordo com a expressão "voto vencido por unanimidade". Contudo, note que no seu exemplo consta apenas "voto vencido".

Comment: Agora entendi. Obrigado por explicar, Centaurus.

Answer (score -1):

Pode ser chamado de " oposição"

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição. Um problema que vejo nessa sugestão, contudo, é que "oposição" só denota posicionamento, não que seja o _único_ contrário.

Answer (score -1):

pode ser chamado de voto de oposição ou ovelha negra.

Comment: Não me parece uma boa. Afinal, um voto que se opuser a algo proposto não poderia ser chamado também de oposição?